# Error in Unity: Lightning.SetColors(Color, Color)' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, int

The errors is exactly:

> Error (1)
>
> Assets/_dinostudios123/Match-Tree Engine/Scripts/Effects/Lightning.cs(7,14): error CS0501: `Lightning.SetColors(Color, Color)' must have a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
>
> This error is caused by changing the [line.SetColors(color, color);] by having to add public void SetColors (Color start, Color end);
>
> Error (2)
>
> Assets/_dinostudios123/Match-Tree Engine/Scripts/Effects/Lightning.cs(30,14): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.LineRenderer.SetVertexCount(int)' is obsolete:` Use numPositions instead.'

Could anyone determine why the error codes are coming up when adding in the line of code to correct the color start and color end and to correct int count per line?

---

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

// Lightning effect

public class Lightning: MonoBehaviour {

    public void SetColors (  //The error is applied to this line of code
        Color start,
        Color end
    );

    public void SetVertexCount (
        int count
    );

    public Transform start; // start object
    public Transform end; //end object
    public int bend = 2; // bends count
    public Vector3[] bendPoint; // points of bending
    public Color color; // start lightning color
   
    public string sortingLayer;
    public int sortingOrder;

    LineRenderer line;  //LineRenderer Line
    float distance = 0f;
    float lastTime = -100f;
    float frequency = 20f;
    bool  destroing = false;
    Vector3 a;
    Vector3 b;
    
    
    void  Start (){
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        bendPoint = new Vector3[bend];
        line.SetColors(color, color);  //color, color
        line.SetVertexCount(bend + 2);
        line.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerName = sortingLayer;
        line.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;

        transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Slots").transform;
    }
    
    void  Update (){
        if (end == null || !end.gameObject.activeSelf || start == null || !start.gameObject.activeSelf) {
            Remove();
            return;
        }
        
        if (!destroing) {
            a = start.position;
            b = end.position;
        }
        distance = (a - b).magnitude;
        if (lastTime + 1f/frequency < Time.time) {
            lastTime = Time.time;
            for (int i = 0; i < bendPoint.Length; i++)
                bendPoint[i] = new Vector3((2f * Random.value - 1f) * 0.1f * distance, (2f * Random.value - 1f) * 0.1f * distance, 0f);
        }
        line.SetPosition(0, a);
        for (int i= 1; i < bend + 1; i++) {
            line.SetPosition(i, Vector3.Lerp(a, b, (1f * i)/(bend+1)) + bendPoint[i-1]);
        }
        line.SetPosition(bend + 1, b);
    }

    public void Remove() {
        StartCoroutine(FadeOut());
    }

    IEnumerator FadeOut (){
        if (destroing) yield break;
        destroing = true;
        while (GetComponent<Animation>().isPlaying) yield return 0;
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("LightningFadeOut");
        while (GetComponent<Animation>().isPlaying) yield return 0;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // function of creating new lightning effect
    public static Lightning CreateLightning (int bend, Transform start, Transform end, Color color) {
        Lightning newLightning = ContentAssistant.main.GetItem<Lightning> ("Lightning");
        newLightning.bend = bend;
        newLightning.start = start;
        newLightning.end = end;
        newLightning.color = color;
        return newLightning;
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out and fixed the file.  All I did was create a body call in the following format:  public void SetColors (Color start, Color end){
 SetColors(color, color);
 }  for the color issue and public void SetVertexCount (int count){
 SetVertexCount(bend + 2);
 } for the int issue

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning you that you've defined methods with parameters but no bodies.

Adjusting your formatting makes it easier to see what it's complaining about:

```
public void SetColors(Color start, Color end);

public void SetVertexCount(int count);
```

You need to define bodies for those methods.

```
public void SetColors(Color start, Color end)
{
    // set the starting and ending colors
}

public void SetVertexCount(int count)
{
    // set the vertex count
}
```

Comment: ya I edited the file like you said before you mentioned it.  I was thinking that and it worked.  Thanks